# how to realise the new OAuth when using objectiveFlickr on mac app

Tags: objective-c

I used the example OAuthTransitionMac,it is OK for the old auth,but when using the new OAuth it got the error

> An error occurred in the stage "OAuth", error: Error
>   Domain=org.lukhnos.ObjectiveFlickr Code=2147418116
>   UserInfo=0x101e515e0 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
>   (org.lukhnos.ObjectiveFlickr error 2147418116.)",

I setted breakpoint and run,when using new OAuth the request token isn't successfully obtained and it got into

```
- (void)flickrAPIRequest:(OFFlickrAPIRequest *)inRequest didFailWithError:(NSError *)inError.
```

I had read the document on the http://blog.lukhnos.org/post/11275346353/flickr-oauth-support-in-objectiveflickr but couldn't solve it.

Please someone help me!

Comment: thanks the people on the Flickr API/Discuss .according to the resource http://www94.flickr.mud.yahoo.com/groups/api/discuss/72157628028927244/,I have solve it,the result is that my computer's time was wrong,when I set the time again then that's OK.

Comment: I have the same problem and I tried to follow your link but it's broken... could you please me explain how to fix the issue or give me the right page?

Comment: I solved my problem... I followed the sample apps that ships with objectiveflickr

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue where I was logging the user out, but I was not setting the oAuthToken && oAuthTokenSecret to nil on my OFFlickrAPIContext object when I was trying to log in with a different user. Once I set those two variable to nil, then it logged in fine and I no longer got this error.