# Flicker TimeStamp

Tags: iphone, timestamp, flickr

When i try autotization on flicker i get error

```
org.lukhnos.ObjectiveFlickr Code=2147418116 "The operation couldn\u2019t be completed. 
(org.lukhnos.ObjectiveFlickr error 2147418116.)" UserInfo=0x4c9000 
AuthError=oauth_problem=timestamp_refused
```

I try this [how to realise the new OAuth when using objectiveFlickr on mac app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189129/how-to-realise-the-new-oauth-when-using-objectiveflickr-on-mac-app) but all link is broken 
Who can help me with that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your device time is set properly. If it's not, it will give the specified error message. Basically it's related to your device time and server time. If you set the device time to existing time it will work as expected.